# XslTransform class is deprecated after .NET conversion

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I had XslTransform in an old program, and after converting the code the the .NET F 3.5, the compiler said that XslTransform is deprecated and replaced by XslCompiledTransform.

This is the old code :

```
XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
xslt.Load(xslTemplate);
xslt.Transform(xPathNav, null, fileStream, null);
```

I've changed the code to look like this :

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(xslTemplate); 
xslt.Transform(xPathNav, fileStream);
```

And now I get :

> cannot convert from
>   'System.IO.FileStream' to
>   'System.Xml.XmlWriter'

I tried to correct that by adding doing this :

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(fileStream);
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, xslt.OutputSettings);
xslt.Transform(doc, writer);
```

I don't get errors anymore, but I the code is not doing XML transformation.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, xslt.OutputSettings);``
This writes to the console have you checked it? try writer.close() or flush()

Comment: What does "but the code is not doing XML transformation" mean - you are not getting an output file created? the output file contains XML but it's the same as the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
xslt.Load(xslTemplate);
xslt.Transform(xPathNav, null, fileStream, null);
```

can be written as follows with XslCompiledTransform

```
XslTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(xslTemplate);
xslt.Transform(xPathNav, null, fileStream);
```

Answer (score 3):

MSDN actually has a full article on [Migrating From XslTransform to XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f54faw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In the first couple of code snippets, you seem to be using `fileStream` for output and `xPathNav` for input.

But in the last snippet, you're using `fileStream` (via `doc`) for input.

Did you really change `fileStream` to be your input document, or is this a mistake?

Comment: It's not a mistake, because the Transform function does not accept a FileStreal in parameter, so I found that code in microsoft website in put in my code. Have you any suggestions to make work using FileStream ?

Comment: @dotNET: I understand that you can't pass a fileStream directly to Transform() anymore. But you were initially using fileStream as the **output** (*2nd* parameter, in your 2nd snippet), whereas in your 3rd snippet you're using doc (which is derived from fileStream) as your **input**. Is it really supposed to have changed from output to input?